# Jquery - Selecting a item by ID not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm doing an ionic (angular) app and I have the following simple code  at the head of one of my templates:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    alert($('#amountID').attr('id'));

});
</script>
</head>
...
<label class="aquitext item item-input" id="amountID">
```

I used to have the tradicional javascript onclick("blablabla") and it worked to a point but I decided to shift it to jquery and now I'm so stuck I had to remove and simplify it to this point. I've tried multiple permutations of this, including using angular's .element but I keep getting "undefined" on the alert.  What am I doing wrong?

(No I don't get any errors on the console)

Edit: It seems it might be related to the fact that I have afterwards an ionic slide-box, thought I have little clue as to how to circumvent it. For now, I removed the slider boxes. Seems to have "fixed" it.

the full structure is, after the script (I trimmed some of the stuff out):

```
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <ion-view>
    <ion-content>                          
        <ion-slide-box>
            <ion-slide> 
            </ion-slide>
            <ion-slide>             
                                <div class="subtitle">blabla</div>

                                <form name="newaquisition">

                                    <label class="aquitext item item-input" id="amountID">
                                        <input ng-model='newaquisubmission.amount' type='number' placeholder='aquisition value' required>
                                    </label>


                                </form>
            </ion-slide>

        </ion-slide-box>
</ion-view>


</ion-content>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems to work here... https://jsfiddle.net/fqq5134L/

Comment: It would seem that your `#amountID` element doesn't actually exist.  Are you sure it's really there?  Try alerting `document.getElementById("amountID")`

Comment: `$(document).ready` is worthless in an ionic/angular app. Most of the DOM gets created after that. What do you need to do?

Comment: [Voting to close this as off-topic (#2)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) because the problem isn't reproducable with the provided code.

Comment: Do you have multiple elements with that id? That will cause you issues like this.

Comment: have you tried to use angular's `angular.element(document.querySelector('#amountID'));` ?

Comment: Please use the jquery service from angular provided https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: Charlietfl: I'm just trying to access an element inside of the html, basically change the css as the user clicks and does stuff. 

twsawf: no! :(

chaos505: I have, it returns an object Object but all attempts to actually verify it's the right one have failed, since it returns object Object for bogus ids I'm assuming it's not really finding the right one.

Answer (score 1):

Is the label in your HTML or is this part of some template and is added to the DOM by angular?

If you run the JS in the console, does it work? Then it's most likely a timing-problem. `$(document).ready` seems to be to early.

try `$scope.init` in your angular-controller

Comment: added the init and it did nothing. I forgot to mention this but it seems to be related to having a ionic slide-box before, for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code; It should work.

Despite that, try creating a variable within the function and then using that variable as the value of alert. For instance,

```
    var x = $('#amountID').attr('id');
    alert(x);
```

If that doesn't work. You probably have an error elsewhere in your code.

Have you referenced a jQuery library (`<script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>`)?

Comment: OP stated `(No I don't get any errors on the console)`

Answer (score 0):

Seem that you don't push the jquery source, this code is correct:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            alert($('#amountID').attr('id'));
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<label class="aquitext item item-input" id="amountID">

</body>

</html>
```